# disable submit button in mvc after server side model validation passes

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I have client side validations of java script and model state validations in controller, related to file attachment.
I want to disable my save (submit) button once it clicked. 
I have checked all solution given at stack overflow links related to this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submitBtn").click(function () {
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',true);
        $('#yourFormId').submit();
    });
});
```

**MVC**

```
public actionresult Save(LatestUpdatemaster objUpdate,HttppostedFileBase filename){
    string strResult="";
    strResult = Utility.UploadUpdateDocument(filename,foldername);
    if(strResult != "1"){
        ModelState.AddModelError("FileName",strResult);
    }
    else{
        //Save code...
    }
}
```

Also tried this,

```
$('#form').one('submit',function(){ $(this).find('input[type="submit"]).attr('onclick','his.style.opacity="0.6";retu‌​rn false;');
```

**Code Creating Button**

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" name="Save" id="Save" />
```

**Client Side - View**

```
$('#Save').click(function(e){
    Duplicatevalidation();
    if($'#Updatename').text().trim() == ''){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

If I do it client side then values won't submit to controller.
Also I want server side model validation completed 
and then make it disable      for not submitting form twice.
Please guide.

Comment: There are lot of options to maintain  it properly/disabling form submit twice on client side!!

Comment: I have tried all and it works also, but form value does not get submit to controller.

Comment: Then just post what you've tried!! So that we'll get some idea on what kind of problem you are facing..

Comment: $('#form').one('submit',function(){ $(this).find('input[type="submit"]).attr('onclick','his.style.opacity="0.6";return false;');

Comment: not like this!! Edit your question!! Add relevant `html` + `js` + `controller` method!!

Comment: there is something like .one() function check that that will do your work,http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Tried all this, given in my edited question. It is not working when using model state validations on server side..., as i need to click it again if validation fires from server side.

Comment: can we see your  code for creating button ??

Comment: are you using ajax ? change your button type to button rather than submit and use ajax

Comment: which browser you are using is it ie8??

Comment: i am using chrome. And any other solution except ajax , as i need to do it to my existing site, which has many controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".submitBtn").click(function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled',true);
         $('#yourFormId').submit();
        });
     });
```

Comment: It is not working, it disables button and won't fire server side validations.

Comment: Also post your HTML form